# How do I debug why a gem install fails?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install [geoutm](https://github.com/tallakt/geoutm) using `gem install geoutm`. The Github repository doesn't have an issues page, so I'm trying to fix the issue myself then submit a pull request. This is the issue:

```
$ gem install geoutm
Fetching: geoutm-1.0.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed geoutm-1.0.1
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    no implicit conversion of Array into String
```

It says "successfully installed", but trying to require the gem fails. Verbose install isn't much more useful:

```
$ gem install geoutm --verbose
HEAD https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
HEAD https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
GET https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
Installing gem geoutm-1.0.1
/home/tomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/geoutm-1.0.1/spec/latlon_spec.rb
/home/tomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/geoutm-1.0.1/spec/geoutm_spec.rb
/home/tomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/geoutm-1.0.1/spec/spec_helper.rb
/home/tomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/geoutm-1.0.1/spec/utm_spec.rb
/home/tomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/geoutm-1.0.1/spec/testdata.yaml
/home/tomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/geoutm-1.0.1/spec/spec.opts
/home/tomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/geoutm-1.0.1/spec/ellipsoid_spec.rb
/home/tomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/geoutm-1.0.1/lib/geoutm/utm_zones.rb
/home/tomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/geoutm-1.0.1/lib/geoutm/geo_utm_exception.rb
/home/tomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/geoutm-1.0.1/lib/geoutm/utm.rb
/home/tomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/geoutm-1.0.1/lib/geoutm/ellipsoid.rb
/home/tomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/geoutm-1.0.1/lib/geoutm/latlon.rb
/home/tomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/geoutm-1.0.1/lib/geoutm.rb
/home/tomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/geoutm-1.0.1/LICENCE
/home/tomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/geoutm-1.0.1/README.rdoc
/home/tomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/geoutm-1.0.1/History.txt
Successfully installed geoutm-1.0.1
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    no implicit conversion of Array into String
```

The gem works flawlessly when downloaded manually and used without installation.

The issue is that I don't know how to figure out where the type error occurs. I can't find any install logs or more verbose output flags. Any idea how I can figure out this error?

Comment: try this `gem check geoutm --debug` or `gem check geoutm --backtrace`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the output from

```
$ gem install --backtrace ...
```

you can further do

```
$ byebug /home/tallakt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/gem install geoutm-1.0.1.gem
```

Inside byebyg type:

```
(byebug) break /home/tallakt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/rubygems_hook.rb:171
Created breakpoint 1 at /home/tallakt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rdoc-4.0.1/lib/rdoc/rubygems_hook.rb:171
(byebug) c
```

I am working on finding the bug in geoutm, but for now installation is possible using the

```
$ gem install -N geoutm
```

that skips RDoc generation

Comment: Updated in geoutm v 1.0.2

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to Arup Rakshit's comment I tried this command:

```
gem install geoutm --debug --backtrace --verbose
```

And I got a nice backtrace of the error:

```
Exception `TypeError' at /home/tomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rdoc/options.rb:407 - no implicit conversion of Array into String
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    no implicit conversion of Array into String
    /home/tomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rdoc/options.rb:407:in `exist?'
    /home/tomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rdoc/options.rb:407:in `block in check_files'
    /home/tomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rdoc/options.rb:406:in `delete_if'
    /home/tomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rdoc/options.rb:406:in `check_files'
    /home/tomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rdoc/options.rb:480:in `finish'
    /home/tomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rdoc/options.rb:1037:in `parse'
    /home/tomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rdoc/rubygems_hook.rb:162:in `block in generate'
    /home/tomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rdoc/rubygems_hook.rb:159:in `chdir'
    /home/tomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rdoc/rubygems_hook.rb:159:in `generate'
    /home/tomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rdoc/rubygems_hook.rb:54:in `block in generation_hook'
    /home/tomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rdoc/rubygems_hook.rb:53:in `each'
    /home/tomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rdoc/rubygems_hook.rb:53:in `generation_hook'
    /home/tomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:382:in `call'
    /home/tomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:382:in `block (2 levels) in install'
    /home/tomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:381:in `each'
    /home/tomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:381:in `block in install'
    /home/tomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:401:in `in_background'
    /home/tomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:380:in `install'
    /home/tomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:166:in `block in execute'
    /home/tomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:158:in `each'
    /home/tomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:158:in `execute'
    /home/tomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/command.rb:305:in `invoke_with_build_args'
    /home/tomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:170:in `process_args'
    /home/tomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:130:in `run'
    /home/tomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:60:in `run'
    /home/tomas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/gem:22:in `<main>'
```

Comment: @ArupRakshit: I'm not sure. I didn't use the `gem check` command, I just tried the flags you provided on the install command.