# How to install Jekyll on Mac 10.11.6

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, jekyll, failed-installation

Hello and thanks for your help in advance. 
I'm having trouble installing Jekyll because I receive the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EINVAL)
Invalid argument
```

This is slightly different than the question already posted, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31567029/how-can-i-install-jekyll-on-osx-10-11) I've also followed all of those recommendations but nothing is working.

- Current xCode version: 8
- Current Ruby version: ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]

Here is the backtrace of the install:

```
Lisas-MBP:gems LMS$ gem install jekyll --backtrace
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EINVAL)
Invalid argument
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/resolv.rb:672:in     `clock_gettime'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/resolv.rb:672:in `request'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/resolv.rb:531:in `block in   fetch_resource'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/resolv.rb:1103:in `block (3   levels) in resolv'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/resolv.rb:1101:in `each'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/resolv.rb:1101:in `block (2   levels) in resolv'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/resolv.rb:1100:in `each'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/resolv.rb:1100:in `block in   resolv'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/resolv.rb:1098:in `each'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/resolv.rb:1098:in `resolv'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/resolv.rb:522:in `fetch_resource'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/resolv.rb:512:in `each_resource'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/resolv.rb:493:in `getresource'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:99:in `api_endpoint'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/source.rb:47:in `api_uri'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/source.rb:86:in `dependency_resolver_set'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/resolver/best_set.rb:24:in `block in pick_sets'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/source_list.rb:98:in `each'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/source_list.rb:98:in `each_source'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/resolver/best_set.rb:23:in `pick_sets'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/resolver/best_set.rb:29:in `find_all'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/resolver/installer_set.rb:152:in `find_all'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/resolver/installer_set.rb:55:in `add_always_install'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:474:in `resolve_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:239:in `install_gem'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:300:in `block in install_gems'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:296:in `each'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:296:in `install_gems'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:203:in `execute'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/command.rb:308:in `invoke_with_build_args'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:169:in `process_args'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:139:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:55:in `run'
/usr/local/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

Here is my `gem env`

```
Lisas-MBP:Code LMS$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.1
- RUBY VERSION: 2.3.1 (2016-04-26 patchlevel 112) [x86_64-darwin15]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
- USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/LMS/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/LMS/.gem/specs
- SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/etc
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
- ruby
- x86_64-darwin-15
- GEM PATHS:
 - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
 - /Users/LMS/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
 - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1_1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
 - :update_sources => true
 - :verbose => true
 - :backtrace => false
 - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:
 - https://rubygems.org/
- SHELL PATH:
 - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin
 - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin
 - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin
 - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin
 - /opt/local/bin
 - /opt/local/sbin
 - /usr/local/bin
 - /usr/local/bin
 - /usr/bin
 - /bin
 - /usr/sbin
 - /sbin
 - /user/local/bin
 - /Users/LMS/.rvm/bin
 - /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin
```

Comment: Not much useful information about this EINVAL, maybe try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078183/how-do-i-debug-why-a-gem-install-fails to get more debug info.

Comment: @halfelf I've edited the post to include the backtrace

Comment: @halfelf I've also added my gem env, I think the problem is I have multiple gem paths, one of which does match my installation directory.

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to successfully install jekyll on my Mac but I'm not using system Ruby. I'd highly recommend using [RBEnv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) to manage your Ruby installation on OSX. You'll find it much easier to work with than trying to deal with the system version or the Brew version. With it you can swap out Ruby versions easily and gem management is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses.
I ended up uninstalling ruby and re-installing it. 
Then I started getting other issues, but new issues are good!
And [this](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4093) finally fixed it.

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin/ jekyll
```

Now I'm running ruby 2.0. Hope this helps, let me know if anyone has any questions!